# Algorithm to find historical operations in a Tree directory structure

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, tree, time-complexity

There is an interesting problem I have come across. There is a directory tree lets call that `T`

Now in the directory structure there are 3 operations are allowed

```
1. Add a file or another directory under some parent directory
2. Remove a file or another directory
3. Modify that is move a file / directory from one parent directory to another.
```

Now you perform the above 3 operations in any sequence on the directory `T`. That operations will give another directory structure , lets call it `T'`.

> The question is if you have `T` and `T'` would be able to find the **minimum** **sequence** of operations `S` which transformed `T` to `T'`.

For example

```
 T = 
 root/ 
 ---- a/
       --- file1.txt

 T' = 

 root/ 
 ---- a/

 S = {Delete root/a/file1.txt}

 Another example 

 T = 
 root/ 
 ---- a/


 T' = 

 root/ 
 ---- a/
       ---file1.txt

 S = {Add root/a/file1.txt}
```

Comment: would you please elaborate your question....

Comment: I am not sure what elaboration you want. In a directory you can change files like , delete/add etc and after that the previous directory is transformed from its old state to new state. The question is to find the minimum set of operations which could change to the new state

Comment: @Krpa I have added an example

Comment: If `T` was originally changed to `T'` using a sequence (not set!) of operations `So`, is the minimum `Sm` required to be a subset of `So`, or can `Sm` be composed of entirely different operations?  For example it is obvious that `mv foo bar; mv bar foo` can be removed completely, but can `mv foo bar; mv bar baz` be changed to `mv foo baz` or not?

Comment: Yes that will be a sequence. I have changed it. `Sm` could be  different sequence of operation than `So`.  But the result should be identical. As long as the sequences makes same T' and it is a minimum sequence it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can depth first search on two trees simultaneously and at file level we can use checksum to check if two files are identical. The operation at file level can be O(n^2) if all files are renamed and n is number of files in a directory, for better performance we can maintain a manifest at each directory level with checksum of each file captured (file operations need to be modified and will be more complex but this is not required if we don't want to do this operation frequently). This can generate lot more output if a directory is moved, in that case we can compute a cumulative checksum like thing for each directory and save it for a level order traversal later. While doing a level order traversal later we can optimize the output. (Just a thought)